# What does platform type "Internal" refer to on Google Cast SDK Developer Console Statistics?

Tags: statistics, google-cast

Hoping that someone might shed some light here. There is no indication what the `Internal` figure means, nor how it works into the `Total` calculations.

I'm trying to figure out what `Internal` means, and why the total unique devices count doesn't add up to the unique devices by platform total. Ideally would like to know exactly what the % is of `chromecast senders` - `ios` versus `web` versus `android`.

*Google Cast SDK Developer Console Statistics*:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is internal processes taking place within the Chromecast devices. Please disregard that count.

Comment: Thanks @Anjaneesh!  That solves part of the issue, but how do I then reconcile against the total device count? If I disregard the `Internal` numbers I still can't account for the `Total` device numbers that are being returned. If I combine just the actual platforms in isolation is this an accurate breakdown?

Comment: If a device received a cast request from both Android and iOS senders on that aggregation period, then that table is double counting that device in the "% of Total devices" column. This would also happen if there was a breakdown table by country, though it wouldn't be as obvious.
A simple fix would be to use the total device count from the above table as the denominator.